# How do I separate the images in the same div when using element.down() function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I have the following div:

```
  <div class="wrap-header-requirements">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th class="wrap-header-requirementsTHName">NAME  <img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" class="studentRequirementSort" />
    </th>
    <th class="wrap-header-requirementsGeneral">CLASS<img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" class="studentRequirementSort" />
    </th>
    <th class="wrap-header-requirementsGeneral">GROUP  <img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" class="studentRequirementSort" />
</th>
<th class="wrap-header-requirementsGeneral">SYSTEM  <img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" class="studentRequirementSort" />
</th>
<th class="wrap-header-requirementsTHCentered">FEES (USD)  <img src="resources/images/arrow-bottom-1-512.png" class="studentRequirementSort" /></th></tr></table></div>
```

Ok so now my problem is that if I have the container of the above div with me in the variable element and I do element.down('img') I get the first image but how do I get the rest of the images, I cannot set a different class for every element that is my restriction but any other ideas or code would be really appreciated

Comment: .down() is not a standard part of JavaScript. Are you using a library?

Comment: I am using sencha touch

Answer (score 1):

If you have ExtJS available you can do this to get all `img`-tags inside `.wrap-header-requirements`:

```
Ext.query('.wrap-header-requirements img');
```

Note: this will return an array of DOM nodes rather than Ext components.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution but I needed the class not the image node because I have to do some further operations on that class. But I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`element.query('img');`

It means grab any child nodes of `element` at any depth that match the selector `img`.

[Documentation link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-query)